# Simulator freezes – Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Recently I started to experience problems with iOS Simulator. It's strange but it never happened before.
When I run project it works fine for 10 minutes or so. But then it writes this messages to console:

```
Exiting because our workspace host has disconnected.
```

and

```
XPC connection interrupted
```

and simulator freezes (doesn't respond to touches).
Restarting of simulator doesn't help, I get alert in Xcode:

```
Error returned in reply: Connection invalid
Software caused connection abort
```

If I restart Xcode it works fine again... for next few minutes.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I had Xcode 9 beta installed alongside Xcode 8.3.3 and called `xcode-select` to switch to Xcode 9. Looks like this was root of an issue.

When I switch back via `xcode-select -s <path/to/Xcode.app>` this issue disappeared.